# What's wrong with my alias config in webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, alias

In my react project I wanna use sweetalert library like that `import Swal from "sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2";` instead of using like that `import Swal from "sweetalert2"`

That's why instead of changing it everywhere, i wanted to manage it from webpack. So I wrote alias for it

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'sweetalert': path.resolve(__dirname,'./node_modules/sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.js'),
    },
},
```

And tried to import the library, but it seems doesn't work. Maybe my webpack.config.js file doesn't work.

```
import Swal from "sweetalert";
```

I also tried like that;

```
'sweetalert': 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.js',
```

I am using

react 17.0.2
webpack 5.65.0

And the scripts file in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "analyze": "cross-env REACT_APP_INTERACTIVE_ANALYZE=1 npm run build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,css,scss,html}\"",
    "rtl": "webpack"
  },
```

> Note: I named it 'sweetalert' for testing.